# Converting acceleration over time to velocity or speed in code

Tags: java, c#, accelerometer

I have acceleration data from a sensor. X Y & Z. I move the senor in the Y axis. Mostly in a straight line. So I ignore x & z.

From the sensor documentation 5.2.1 Acceleration output：

ax=((AxH<<8)|AxL)/32768*16g(g is Gravity acceleration，9.8m/s2)

ay=((AyH<<8)|AyL)/32768*16g(g is Gravity acceleration，9.8m/s2)

az=((AzH<<8)|AzL)/32768*16g(g is Gravity acceleration，9.8m/s2)

The data is in (m/s2)

I need a simple calculation that java or C# can take easily. I want to write something in code that calculates the acceleration over time to maximum velocity and average velocity. I need a "speed" value that I can display. For Ex. Max speed 12MPH and Average Speed 8MPH.

--EDIT with better data moving it 12 inches
--This is the working code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalculateSpeed
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<TimeAccelData> timeVsAccelerationData = new List<TimeAccelData>();

            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() { Time = 910.614, Acceleration = 0.0001 });//not  Moving
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() { Time = 910.655, Acceleration = 0.0025 });//Moving
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() { Time = 910.655, Acceleration = 0.0045 });
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() { Time = 910.655, Acceleration = 0.0098 });
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() { Time = 910.684, Acceleration = 0.0059 });
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() { Time = 910.684, Acceleration = 0.0079 });
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() { Time = 910.684, Acceleration = 0.0094 });
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.684, Acceleration = 0.0186});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.684, Acceleration = 0.0357});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.684, Acceleration = 0.0582});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.684, Acceleration = 0.0611});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.695, Acceleration = 0.1368});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.714, Acceleration = 0.1207});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.729, Acceleration = 0.1661});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.734, Acceleration = 0.1632});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.747, Acceleration = 0.1627});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.754, Acceleration = 0.1788});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.764, Acceleration = 0.3746});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.816, Acceleration = 0.4893});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.82, Acceleration = 0.5806});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.82, Acceleration = 0.627});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.849, Acceleration = 0.565});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.849, Acceleration = 0.5899});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.849, Acceleration = 0.5968});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.849, Acceleration = 0.6632});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.849, Acceleration = 0.6749});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.849, Acceleration = 0.7237});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.849, Acceleration = 0.7511});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.866, Acceleration = 0.692});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.9, Acceleration = 0.7227});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.902, Acceleration = 0.7384});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.902, Acceleration = 0.6436});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.908, Acceleration = 0.6959});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.915, Acceleration = 0.5738});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.929, Acceleration = 0.4796});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.935, Acceleration = 0.3443});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.949, Acceleration = 0.1803});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 910.952, Acceleration = 0.0601});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.012, Acceleration = -0.1332});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.014, Acceleration = -0.3554});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.015, Acceleration = -0.5414});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.015, Acceleration = -0.6908});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.017, Acceleration = -0.7807});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.018, Acceleration = -0.9779});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.031, Acceleration = -0.8061});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.066, Acceleration = -0.9692});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.11, Acceleration = -1.0146});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.11, Acceleration = -1.5878});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.11, Acceleration = -1.0785});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.11, Acceleration = -1.1225});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.11, Acceleration = -1.1557});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.11, Acceleration = -1.0395});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.113, Acceleration = -0.9071});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.115, Acceleration = -0.4555});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.129, Acceleration = -0.3305});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() {Time = 911.136, Acceleration = -0.3266});
            timeVsAccelerationData.Add(new TimeAccelData() { Time = 911.164, Acceleration = 0.002 });//STOPPED MOVING

        //initial speed = 0.0001 and distance = 0.
        var distance = RiemannIntegration(new List<TimeAccelData>(RiemannIntegration(timeVsAccelerationData, 0).ToArray()),0).Last().Acceleration;
        //distance equals 0.028999999999996362 meters to inches = 1.1417322834644237
        //fixed the double integration and now the value is lower
        //distance equals 0.02675412494998913
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TimeAccelData> RiemannIntegration(List<TimeAccelData> xy, double initialValue)
        {
            var res = initialValue;
            yield return (new TimeAccelData() {Time = xy[0].Time, Acceleration = initialValue});

            for (var i = 1; i < xy.Count; i++)
            {
                res += (xy[i].Time - xy[i - 1].Time) * (xy[i].Acceleration + xy[i - 1].Acceleration) / 2;
                yield return (new TimeAccelData() {Time = xy[i].Time, Acceleration = res});
            }
        }

        public class TimeAccelData
        {
            public double Time { get; internal set; }
            public double Acceleration { get; internal set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to integrate the forces and integration adds a ton of error, it will be useful only for a couple of seconds. Accelerometer isn't the appropiate sensor to get speed. If you have GPS better use the computed speed.

Comment: Without knowing the initial velocity, this can't be done.  Even if you _do_ know the initial velocity, it's not going to be terribly accurate, because you won't know the acceleration in the intervals between measurements.

Comment: GUSMAN you can't use GPS for 6 inches of movement. Dawood, The starting speed is Zero.  You can determine the speed from a fixed position to end point with time and acceleration. I can assume a constant positive acceleration between each acceleration. This is calculable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity is the integration of acceleration. If the initial velocity is 0, then you could evaluate the velocity with a [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral)(*); the area of the acceleration function.

For a general function `fx` you could do:

```
public static double RiemannIntegration
    (Func<double, double> fx,
     double x0,
     double x1,
     double step)
{
    var previous = x0;
    var res = 0d;
    var semiStep = step / 2;

    for (var x = x0 + step; x < x1; x += step)
    {
        res += semiStep * (fx(x) + fx(previous));
        previous = x;
    }

    res += (x1 - previous) / 2 * (fx(x1) + fx(previous));
    return res;
}
```

But maybe a more specific implementation is more useful for your scenario; given a sequence of `(t, acc)` data, evaluate the Riemann integral with a variable step defined by each `t`. This implementation considers a linear variation of the acceleration inside each interval:

```
public static double RiemannIntegration(
    (double X, double Y)[] xy)
{
    var res = 0d;

    for (var i = 1; i < xy.Length; i++)
    {
        res += (xy[i].X - xy[i - 1].X) * (xy[i].Y + xy[i - 1].Y) / 2;
    }

    return res;
}
```

UPDATE: Based on your comments, you ultimately want to evaluate the distance covered. You can do this by integrating two times the acceleration, but in order to do that, you actually need to return integrated curves, not total values. The following implementation will do that:

```
public static IEnumerable<(double X, double Y)> RiemannIntegration(
    (double X, double Y)[] xy, double initialValue)
{
    var res = initialValue;
    yield return (xy[0].X, initialValue);

    for (var i = 1; i < xy.Length; i++)
    {
        res += (xy[i].X - xy[i - 1].X) * (xy[i].Y + xy[i - 1].Y) / 2;
        yield return (xy[i].X, res);
    }
}
```

And now to evaluate distance form acceleration data you'd do:

```
var timeVsAccelerationData = new[] { (t0, a0), (t1, a1), ... };

//initial speed and distance are zero.
var distance = RiemmanIntegral(RiemannIntegral(
    timeVsAccelerationData, 0).ToArray(), 0).Last().Y;
```

(*) The proposed algorithm isn't exactly the Riemann integral, I'm using trapezoidal areas, Riemann integral really uses rectangular areas with a height equal to the function value in the center of the time interval.

Comment: InBetween -- in each equation what is Fx, x0,x1,Step and  the second X= time,Y = acceleration?

Comment: @SteveColeman In the first equation, `fx` would be a lambda expression that represents the function `acc(t)` and `x0` and `x1` would be the initial and final times you want to consider. `step` defines the time step you want to integrate with, the smaller it is the smaller the error due to considering linear variation between `ti` and `ti+1` but it can make `double` representation induced errors grow. In the second equation, `fx` would represent discrete `(t, acc)` data.

Comment: InBetween I am doing some tests on the calculation. I am going to drop the sensor at different heights. i will verify if the Velocity * Time = the distance dropped. If its close to accurate. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @SteveColeman That wont be true. The integration will give you the final speed, not the average speed which seems to be what you want to verify with `Velocity * Time`. You could consider creating a speed "curve" by integrating by intervals the acceleration curve and then integrating the speed curve which will give you distance.

Comment: InBetween, I know you put some time into this. Once we are done. I am going to pout a bounty on it and accept your answer. The help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: InBetween, I put the working code in the question. I made a change or two. Can you look at it an let me know if I did something wrong. I am not getting what I would expect from the calculations. It's C#.

Comment: @SteveColeman I can’t verify right now, but first of all you are integrating only once, you need to integrate *twice* to get distance. Read my updated answer again, specially the example at the end.

Comment: @SteveColeman second, your time steps seem to be tiny,  this could be an issue with doubles.

Comment: @SteveColeman and last, you are only using one acceleration (not X, Y, Z). That’s ok for testing purposes but only if you are moving the sensor in that one direction. Otherwise you’d need to integrate all three directions to get all movement components. Total distance form starting  to final position would be `Sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2 + ...)`.

Comment: The small time steps are correct.. I think. I moved the senors for less than a second. I plan to meter fast single direction impacts with it. So X should be fine. InBetween I updated the code above as well to double process the values.
            //fixed the double integration and now the value is lower
            //distance equals 0.02675412494998913

Comment: @SteveColeman The results seem coherent with the data you've posted; maximum achieved speed (accumulated acc · dt) is around 0.115 m/s, which means there is no way, based on that data, that you are moving more than 30 cm in half a second. Something is wrong with your data, testing or sensors. Maybe you are not moving along a sensor axis and you should be looking at all acceleration components (X, Y and Z)